# Jquery dialog just shows the text message

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have defined a dialog like this:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
        $('#dialog_error').dialog({
            title: 'خطا',
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            show: { effect: 'fade', speed: 500 },
            hide: { effect: 'fade', speed: 500 },
            buttons: {
                'بستن': function () { $("#dialog_error").dialog("close"); }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and at the end of my Html code:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="dialog_error" class ="popup_error"></div>
</body>
```

in a Javascript function, I have:

```
...
alert(data.Message);
$("#dialog_error").html(data.Message);
$("#dialog_error").dialog("open");
...
```

the alert is shown correctly but the dialog doesn't open.
and the value of "data.Message" is shown in the middle of the screen after other "div"s.

why is that?

Comment: Did you add appropriate `css` file for the dialog ?

Comment: is there an error in your console

Comment: Probably it's opened but not visible properly for missing `css` file.

Comment: It's not the css. I can see the alert in my other pages.

Comment: I have this error in my console: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

Comment: I would strongly recommend you do debug when your JQuery doesn't work properly.

Comment: Do you have ``jQuery UI (js & css)`` in your page? ``Object [object Object]`` This means that ``JQuery`` is existing and ``has no method 'dialog'`` means ``jQuery UI (js & css)`` is not existing.

Comment: I added them. now I get this error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $dlg=$('#dialog_error').dialog({
            title: 'خطا',
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            show: { effect: 'fade', speed: 500 },
            hide: { effect: 'fade', speed: 500 },
            buttons: {
                'بستن': function () {$(this).dialog("close");}
            }
        });
```

Make sure that the $dlg variable is in scope where you're wanting to change the content, 
then just a `.html()` call will work, like this:

```
$dlg.dialog('open');
$dlg.html(data.Message);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/nzsb55zk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First problem was adding "jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" to the code. an also using

```
$(document).ready(function () {}
```

to prevent building the dialog before it is opened.